# Sql Server Management Studio v18.4 - cannot edit properties on Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

Back in the day when I worked a lot with SQL Server, I used to be able to open up SSMS, connect to the DB and then in the Object Explorer, edit properties of object like say a user by double clicking on the user and then editing the properties in the resulting dialogue.

I've been gone from Microsoft circles for a while and have a project using it again.

I created the DB (SQL Server) in Azure and downloaded SSMS v18.4.

I am able to connect to the server, see the objects in the Obj Explorer but I cannot dbl click Users (there are no logins in Azure SQL Server...that I can find). I appear to have to edit everything using T-SQL.

Is this because I don't have an enterprise version of SSMS (which I used to use) or is it an artifact of Azure SQL Server? Or do I need to install some extensions to SSMS v18.4?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: It's an artifact of Azure SQL. Things have changed. You might want to also look at "Azure Data Studio" which is an alternative tool to SSMS (but still buggy)

Comment: Thanks Nick. Lotsa stuff has changed since I've been away :)

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL database doesn't support double clicking on the user and then editing the properties in the resulting dialogue.

You must using T-SQL create or alter the login and user, reference [Logins and Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins). Azure SQL only provide the T-SQL way for us.

[image]

That's Azure SQL database feature limit and it has nothing to do with SSMS versions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much Leon!

Comment: @FrankFang You're welcome. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.